# How would I iterate through a list of [[tokens]] and replace them with textbox input?

Tags: java, templates, oop, hashmap

Here is the basic code i'm trying to make work:

```
Field fields[] = SalesLetter.class.getDeclaredFields();
String fieldName;

for (int j = 0, m = fields.length; j < m; j++) {
       fieldName = fields[j].getName(); //example fieldname [[headline]]
       templateHTML = templateHTML.replace(fieldName, Letter.fieldName());
}
```

I believe I'm going about it wrong by trying to getDeclaredFields (which isn't even syntactically correct). When I finished my title, it came up with a few other stackoverflow questions which I read before writing this. They were:

[Best way to replace tokens in a large text template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20267/best-way-to-replace-tokens-in-a-large-text-template)
[Replacing tokens in a string from an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619739/replacing-tokens-in-a-string-from-an-array)

It gave me the idea of reading all legal [[tokens]] from a text file, putting them into a hash (err I mean map, this is java :D), then creating an object reference with the same name as that token.

I can't figure out how I would do such a thing in java specifically, or if that would work. Please assist.

Thanks in advance,

Cody Goodman

Note: I'm trying to make everything as flexible as possible, so maybe in the future I could add things such as "[[tokenname]]:this is token name, you need to really think about what the customer wants to come up with a good token name" in a text file, then those fields are generated on my form, and everything works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to read values from non-static fields of a type, you'll need a reference to an instance of the type:

```
public class ReflectFields {
  static class Letter {
    public int baz = 100;
  }

  static class SalesLetter extends Letter {
    public String foo = "bar";
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // TODO: better exception handling, etc.
    SalesLetter instance = new SalesLetter();
    for (Field field : instance.getClass().getFields()) {
      System.out.format("%s = %s%n", field.getName(), field.get(instance));
    }
  }
}
```

You'll also have to watch for private fields, etc. In general, this approach should be avoided as it breaks encapsulation by looking at class internals.

Consider using the JavaBean API.

```
public class BeanHelper {
  private final Object bean;
  private final Map<String, Method> getters = new TreeMap<String, Method>();

  public BeanHelper(Object bean) {
    this.bean = bean;
    for (PropertyDescriptor pd : Introspector.getBeanInfo(bean.getClass(),
          Object.class).getPropertyDescriptors()) {
      getters.put(pd.getName(), pd.getReadMethod());
    }
  }

  public Set<String> getProperties() { return getters.keySet(); }

  public Object get(String propertyName) {
    return getters.get(propertyName).invoke(bean);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    BeanHelper helper = new BeanHelper(new MyBean());
    for (String prop : helper.getProperties()) {
      System.out.format("%s = %s%n", prop, helper.get(prop));
    }
  }

  public static class MyBean {
    private final String foo = "bar";
    private final boolean baz = true;
    public String getFoo() { return foo; }
    public boolean isBaz() { return baz; }
  }
}
```

Exception handling has been omitted for brevity, so you'll need to add some try/catch blocks (I suggest wrapping the caught exceptions in [IllegalStateException](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalStateException.html#IllegalStateException(java.lang.Throwable))s).

Comment: Just beginning java, so I think i'm going to have to read some javadocs before I fully appreciate this answer. Thanks for the help! I'll see if I can't throw something together with this code.

Answer (score 0):

What about using a template engine like [Freemarker](http://freemarker.org/), [Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/) or [StringTemplate](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ST/):

- replace `[[` by `${` and `]]` by `}`
- create a model from a properties file containing the replacements
- process templateHTML

Here an example with Freemarker (without Exception handling)

```
Configuration config = new Configuration();
StringTemplateLoader loader = new StringTemplateLoader();
config.setTeplateLoader(loader);

Map model = Properites.load(new FileInputStream("tokens.properties"));
loader.putTemplate("html.ftl", templateHTML);
Template template = config.getTemplate("html.ftl");

Writer out = new StringWriter();
template.process(root, out);
String result = out.toString();
```

StringTemplate may be more simple (replace `[[` and `]]` by `$`), but I am not fimilar with it:

```
Map model = Properites.load(new FileInputStream("tokens.properties"));
StringTemplate template = new StringTemplate(templateHTML);
template.setAttributes(model);
String result = template.toString();
```

The `tokens.properties` file looks like:

```
tokenname:this is token name
```

Comment: This looks interesting, and really flexible. I'll see if I can't put code together with this to. Love the simplicity here though. Thanks.